# convert row in data frame to list of lists in r

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply, mapply

I have a data frame consisting of records like the following. A typical row of the data frame, df[1,] looks as follows

```
84745,"F",70,7,"Single",2,"N",4,9,1,1,3,4,4,"2 day","<120 and <80",0,8,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
```

I want to convert it into a variable like myvar below which is of the following type

```
myvar = list( list(84745,"F",70,7,"Single",2,"N",4,9,1,1,3,4,4,"2 day","<120 and <80",0,8,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

I have tried doing the following, but it doesn't work to convert it to a list of lists.

```
myvar <- as.list(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df[1,]))))
```

How can I do that?

EDIT : I have tried myvar = list(unclass(df[14,])). It however fails the call since the formatting of the output myvar is slightly different.

Format of the original line of code

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 21408

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "M"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 69

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "Widowed"
```

Format of myvar = list(unclass(df[14,]))

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$ID
[1] "21408"

[[1]]$GenderCD
[1] "M"

[[1]]$Age
[1] "69"

[[1]]$LOS
[1] "3"

[[1]]$MaritalStatus
[1] "Widowed"
```

Comment: What do you need the list of lists for? That might help in finding a good solution.

Comment: @theWanderer4865, it's for testing a web service deployed on azure which expects inputs to be list of lists

Comment: The edit suggests that you have not provided a correct example. Using `unclass` would not coerce a row from a dataframe to be all the same class. That is something that using `t` would do as pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 myvar <- list( unclass( df[1,] )
```

Explanation: df[1,] is actually still a list but with a "data.frame" class attribute. If you remove its class it's now just an ordinary list. When you conducted the `t(df[1,]`-operation you forced that row to become a column vector which in a dataframe needed to all be the came class so coercion occurred.

If the goal is a row-by-row solution then do this:

```
 myvar <- list()
 for (i in seq(nrow(df)) ) { myvar[[i]]  <-  unclass( df[i,] )}
```

If it also needs to be unnamed which I rather doubt but I suppose it's possible then:

```
 myvar <- list()
 for (i in seq(nrow(df)) ) { myvar[[i]]  <-  unname( unclass( df[i,] )) }
```

I tested the `unname` strategy with:

```
> unname(unclass( data.frame(a=345,b="tyt")[1,]))
[[1]]
[1] 345

[[2]]
[1] tyt
Levels: tyt

attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1
```

Comment: I don't see a problem unless you have problems with unnaming an object.

Comment: set the column names to Null

Comment: @PierreLafortune Was there a problem with using `unname`? And it would have been `NULL`